# Iterate over instances of an ITERABLE class

Tags: python

I have defined the following class

```
class Person(object):        
    _counter = 0
    _instances = []

    def __init__(self, nam):
        self.name = nam
        self._instances.append(self)
        self._id = Person._counter + 1
        Person._counter+=1        

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._id} : Person({self.name})'    

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def iterate(cls):
        return [p for p in Person._instances]
```

I can iterate over the instances of this class with

```
[p for p in Person._instances]
```

I would like to learn how it is possible to arrive at the same result by calling

```
[p for p in Person]
```

I have searched many similar questions and I tried out several suggested answers, without any luck. I am using Python 3.6 Anaconda x64 and in all the solutions I tested on the interpreter I am getting back

```
  [p for p in Person]
  TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable
```

Could you please write exactly how I can execute successfully this [p for p in Person] call to get back the same list as Person.iterate() and Person._instances ?

Comment: In oder to do so, you'd need to let `Person` have a metaclass whose instances are iterable.

Comment: @Rawing No. The question is different.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for pointing that out, retracted my cv.

Comment: I have tried to include __iter__ and __next__  methods in my Person class but I failed with the same exception TypeError: 'type' object is not iterable

Comment: I have also tried in many different ways to include a metaclass and I failed with the same TypeError !!!

Answer (score 9):

You can define an `__iter__` on the metaclass to make the metaclass instance (i.e. `Person`) iterable:

```
class metaclass(type):
   def __iter__(cls):
       return iter(getattr(cls, '_instances', []))

class Person(metaclass=metaclass):  
    # __metaclass__ = metaclass Python 2
    ...
```

Comment: I'd have the metaclass add the attributes and keep them updated as well.

Comment: @chepner Depends. I prefer to keep only non-trivial code in the metaclass so it's highly reusable and lightweight; if I understood you.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye thank you for your answer as I said I have tried similar answers including yours without any luck. I am a user of Python 3.6, and you write that __metaclass__ is for Python 2. So what is the solution in Python 3.6 ?

Comment: @Athanassios The solution is as shown in the updated answer: `class Person(metaclass=metaclass)`

Comment: the code he put is python3 ... the comment is how you would do the same in python 2

Comment: OK, I have missed your updated answer class Person (metaclass=metaclass): That really made the difference and now this works for Python 3.6. Thank you for your prompt reply. Hope that question-answer pair will also help other users that are frustrated with the differences between Python versions.

Answer (score 0):

For clarity purposes I have included the solution and some testing data as it has already been pointed out by "Moses Koledoye" and there is also a useful comment by "chepner" which I tried to take on account.

### Solution

```
class PersonMeta(type):
    _counter = 0     
    _instances = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(getattr(self, '_instances', []))


class Person(metaclass=PersonMeta):

    def __init__(self, nam):
        self.name = nam
        Person._instances.append(self)
        self._id = Person._counter + 1
        Person._counter+=1        

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self._id} : Person({self.name})'
```

---

### Output

```
In [70]: [p for p in Person]
Out[70]: 
[1 : Person(James),
 2 : Person(George),
 3 : Person(Jack),
 4 : Person(Mary),
 5 : Person(Sue),
 6 : Person(James),
 7 : Person(George),
 8 : Person(Jack),
 9 : Person(Mary),
 10 : Person(Sue)]
```

Ideally, I would like to see a more clear separation between the Metaclass and the Class. But I don't know how I can transfer the folowing statements to the MetaPerson. Is that a good idea ? Can you help me with this ?

```
Person._instances.append(self)    
Person._counter+=1
```